# Proguard and Android

Tags: android, proguard

I try to add `com.radaee.pdfex_view.jar` to `proguard`. I added this code

```
    -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keep public class com.radaee.* {
 public static *;
 public static *;
 private static *;
}

-keep public class com.radaee.**
```

to my `project.properties.txt`, but when I go to my `pdf` the app closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 -keep class com.radaee.** {*;}
```